# Qml canvas toDataURL incomplete image

Tags: android, qt, canvas, qml

I'm deploying a qml app that uses a canvas to merge different images and then store it using the [toDataURL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#toDataURL-method) method.

I get a bug only on an android "Lg s3", where the resulting string is always too short (compared with Desktop or other Android apps).

Here is my canvas code:

```
Canvas
{
    id: faceCanvas
    width: canvasSizes
    height: canvasSizes
    visible: false

    renderStrategy: Canvas.Threaded;
    renderTarget: Canvas.Image;

    property var images
    property var callback


    onPaint:
    {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");

        if (images)
        {
            for (y = 0 ;  y< nPieces ; y++)
            {
                ctx.drawImage(images[y], 0, 0, canvasSizes, canvasSizes )
            }
        }

    }

    onPainted:
    {
        if (callback)
        {
            var data = toDataURL('image/png')
            callback(data)
        }
    }
}
```

The output never show the totallity of the image, it shows only a littler part of that, for example:

[image]

The left image is the image processed on canvas, that is shown, and the right one is the toDataURL image result.

I think is a specific device bug!